# css: zooming-out inside the browser moves rightmost floated div below other divs

Tags: html, css

I am seeing something strange in both firefox and chrome when I increase
the zoom level inside these browsers, although I see nothing wrong with
my CSS.
Here is the whole story:

I have a right-floated top-level div containing three right-floated right.
The three inner divs have all box-model measurements in pixels which add
up to the width of the enclosing container. Everything looks fine when
the browser size is 100%, but when I start making the browser smaller
with CTRL+scrollwheel or CTRL+minus the rightmost margin shrinks
down too fast and eventually becomes zero, forcing my rightmost
floated inner div to fall down below the other two!

I can't make sense out of this, almost seems like some integer division
is being performed incorrectly in the browser code, but alas firefox and
chrome both display the same result.

Here is the example (just zoom out with CTRL-minus to see what I mean):

[Click Here to View What I Mean on Example Site](http://timescapezone.com/test/test1/)

Just to narrow things down a bit, the tags of interest are the following:

> ```
> div#mainContent
> div#contentLeft
> div#contentCenter
> div#contentRight
> ```

I've searched stackoverflow for an answer and found the following
posts which seem related to my question but was not able to apply
them to the problem I am experiencing:

> http://
>   stackoverflow.com/questions/6955313/div-moves-incorrectly-on-browser-resize
>
> http://
>   stackoverflow.com/questions/18246882/divs-move-when-resizing-page
>
> http://
>   stackoverflow.com/questions/17637231/moving-an-image-when-browser-resizes
>
> http://
>   stackoverflow.com/questions/5316380/how-to-stop-divs-moving-when-the-browser-is-resized

I've duplicated the html and css code below for your convenience:

Here is the HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Pinco</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="http://pinco.com">
          <img class="logo" src="images/PincoLogo5.png" alt="Pinco" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="titolo">
        <h1>Benvenuti!</h1>
        <h2>Siete arrivati al sito pinco.</h2>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul class="menu"> 
          <li><a href="#">Menù Qui</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menù Quo</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menù Qua</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="mainContent">
      <div id="contentLeft">
        <section>
          <article>
            <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque tempor turpis est, nec varius est pharetra scelerisque. Sed eu pellentesque purus, at cursus nisi. In bibendum tristique nunc eu mattis. Nulla pretium tincidunt ipsum, non imperdiet metus tincidunt ac. In et lobortis elit, nec lobortis purus. Cras ac viverra risus. Proin dapibus tortor justo, a vulputate ipsum lacinia sed. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus sit amet malesuada velit. Fusce diam neque, cursus id dui ac, blandit vehicula tortor.

Phasellus interdum ipsum eu leo condimentum, in dignissim erat tincidunt. Ut fermentum consectetur tellus, dignissim volutpat orci suscipit ac. Praesent scelerisque urna metus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis pulvinar, sem a sodales eleifend, odio elit blandit risus, a dapibus ligula orci non augue. Nullam vitae cursus tortor, eget malesuada lectus. Nulla facilisi. Cras pharetra nisi sit amet orci dignissim, a eleifend odio hendrerit.
            </p>
          </article>
        </section>
      </div>
      <div id="contentCenter">
        <section>
          <article>
            <p>
Maecenas vitae purus at orci euismod pretium. Nam gravida gravida bibendum. Donec nec dolor vel magna consequat laoreet in a urna. Phasellus cursus ultrices lorem ut sagittis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vivamus purus felis, ornare quis ante vel, commodo scelerisque tortor. Integer vel facilisis mauris.
            </p>
            <img src="images/auto1.jpg" width="272" height="272" />
            <p>
In urna purus, fringilla a urna a, ultrices convallis orci. Duis mattis sit amet leo sed luctus. Donec nec sem non nunc mattis semper quis vitae enim. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Suspendisse dictum porta quam, vel lobortis enim bibendum et. Donec iaculis tortor id metus interdum, hendrerit tincidunt orci tempor. Sed dignissim cursus mattis.
            </p>
          </article>
        </section>
      </div>
      <div id="contentRight">
        <section>
          <article>
            <img src="images/auto2.jpg" width="272" height="272" />
            <img src="images/auto3.jpg" width="272" height="272" />
            <p>
Cras eu quam lobortis, sodales felis ultricies, rhoncus neque. Aenean nisi eros, blandit ac lacus sit amet, vulputate sodales mi. Nunc eget purus ultricies, aliquam quam sit amet, porttitor velit. In imperdiet justo in quam tristique, eget semper nisi pellentesque. Cras fringilla eros enim, in euismod nisl imperdiet ac.

Fusce tempor justo vitae faucibus luctus.
            </p>
          </article>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <div class="footerText">
        <p>
Copyright &copy; Pinco
<br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
<br />Fusce ornare turpis orci, nec egestas leo feugiat ac.
<br />Morbi eget sem facilisis, laoreet erat ut, tristique odio. Proin sollicitudin quis nisi id consequat.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="footerLogo">
         <img class="footerLogo" src="images/auto4.jpg" width="80" height="80" />
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the CSS:

```
/* CSS Document */

* { margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; }

body { background: #8B0000; /* darkred */; }

body { margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; }

div#wrapper { margin: 0 auto; width: 960px; height: 100%; background: #FFC0CB /* pink */; }

header { position: relative; background: #005b97; height: 140px; }

header div.logo { float: left; width: 360px; height: 140px; }
header div.logo img.logo { width: 360px; height: 140px;  }

header div.titolo { float: left; padding: 12px 0 0 35px; color: black; }
header div.titolo h1 { font-size: 36px; font-weight: bold; }
header div.titolo h2 { font-size: 24px; font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; color: white;}

header nav { position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0; }

header ul.menu { background: black; }
header ul.menu li { display: inline-block; padding: 3px 15px; font-weight: bold; }

div#mainContent { float: left; width: 100%; /* width: 960px; *//* height: 860px; */ padding: 30px 0; text-align: justify; }

div#mainContent img { margin: 12px 0; }

div#contentLeft { height: 900px; float: left; margin-left: 12px; border: 1px solid black; padding: 15px; width: 272px; background: #ccc; }

div#contentCenter { height: 900px; float: left; margin-left: 12px; border: 1px solid transparent; padding: 15px; width: 272px; background: #E00; }

div#contentRight { height: 900px; float: left; margin-left: 12px; border: 1px solid black; padding: 15px; width: 272px; background: #ccc; }

footer { clear: both; padding: 12px; background: #306; color: white; height: 80px; font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; }

footer div.footerText { float: left; }

footer div.footerLogo { float: right; }

a { color: white; text-decoration: none; }
```

---

### **EDIT 1:**

I've checked all measurements again and carefully plugged in numbers until they
satisfied the following equation for the three uniform columns in the main area
with uniform collapsed margin areas on all sides:

> TEXT_AREA * 3 + MARGIN * 4 + BORDER * 6 = 960px (the width of the
>   wrapper)
>
> TEXT_AREA = WIDTH + 2 * PADDING
>
> BORDER = 1

subject to the margin and padding set to reasonable values of course,
and here are some numbers which seemed OK which solve these constraints:

> TEXT_AREA = 290px
>
> MARGIN = 15px
>
> BORDER = 1px
>
> PADDING = 15px
>
> WIDTH = 268px

which translates to the following:

```
div#mainContent { float: left; width: 960px; padding: 15px 0; text-align: justify; }

div#contentLeft { height: 900px; float: left; margin: 0 0 0 15px; border: 1px solid black; padding: 15px; width: 268px; background: #ccc; }

div#contentCenter { height: 900px; float: left; margin: 0 0 0 15px; border: 1px solid transparent; padding: 15px; width: 268px; background: #E00; }

div#contentRight { height: 900px; float: left; margin: 0 15px 0 15px; border: 1px solid black; padding: 15px; width: 268px; background: #ccc; }
```

However even now that everything is uniform, I still get the problem that when I zoom
out the rightmost column falls down below the others. One solution is to do the following:

```
div#contentRight { height: 900px; float: left; margin: 0 0 /* 15px */ 0 15px; border: 1px solid black; padding: 15px; width: 268px; background: #ccc; }
```

so that now the right column has no right margin, but the visual result is the same.
Now, when I zoom out, the rightmost column does not fall down, but its right margin
is so small compared to the others, so really, there is still a small problem.

### **Edit 2:**

OK, I've done some more searching and found an even better solution. The solution
consists in having the margins in between the div column elements the same and having
the left and right margin adjust automatically. In order to achieve this, I had to
do away with floats, and use "display: inline-block" which IMHO is much more suitable
than floats and was designed for the purpose at hand:

```
div#mainContent { padding: 15px 0; width: 960px; text-align: center; }

div#contentLeft { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; height: 900px; margin: 0 0 0 0/*15px*/; border: 1px solid black; padding: 15px; width: 268px; background: #ccc; }

div#contentCenter { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; height: 900px; margin: 0 0 0 15px; border: 1px solid transparent; padding: 15px; width: 268px; background: #E00; }

div#contentRight { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; height: 900px; margin: 0 0/* 15px */ 0 15px; border: 1px solid black; padding: 15px; width: 268px; background: #ccc; }
```

div#mainContent section { text-align: justify; }

Now, at a normal zoom level all left margins will be 15px plus the last element's right
margin which will also be 15px. On the other hand, if I zoom out, there is some pixel
rounding going on, but the rounding is applied more or less equally on both sides,
which is somewhat better. This works in Firefox.

### **Edit 3:**

Alas, I've tried reducing the in-between margins a bit, which makes the problem
go away with Chrome, but one of the div elements still drops down in IE10.

```
div#mainContent { padding: 15px 0; text-align: center; }

div#contentLeft { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; height: 900px; margin: 0 0 0 0/* 20px increased from 15px */; border: 1px solid black; padding: 15px; width: 268px; background: #ccc; overflow: hidden; }

div#contentCenter { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; height: 900px; margin: 0 0 0 10px/* reduced from 15px */; border: 1px solid transparent; padding: 15px; width: 268px; background: #E00; overflow: hidden; }

div#contentRight { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; height: 900px; margin: 0 0/* 20px increased from 15px */ 0 10px/* reduced from 15px */; border: 1px solid black; padding: 15px; width: 268px; background: #ccc; overflow: hidden; }

div#mainContent section { text-align: justify; }
```

### **Edit 4:**

I've come up with a solution which works in Firefox, Chrome, and IE10.
Basically, I've created three div wrappers around the three columns
and taken measurements again ensuring all measurements are symmetric.
Here is the source code:

HTML File:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Pinco</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="http://pinco.com">
          <img class="logo" src="images/PincoLogo5.png" alt="Pinco" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="titolo">
        <h1>Benvenuti!</h1>
        <h2>Siete arrivati al sito pinco.</h2>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul class="menu"> 
          <li><a href="#">Menù Qui</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menù Quo</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menù Qua</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="mainContent">
      <div id="wrapperLeft">
        <div id="contentLeft">
          <section>
            <article>
              <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque tempor turpis est, nec varius est pharetra scelerisque. Sed eu pellentesque purus, at cursus nisi. In bibendum tristique nunc eu mattis. Nulla pretium tincidunt ipsum, non imperdiet metus tincidunt ac. In et lobortis elit, nec lobortis purus. Cras ac viverra risus. Proin dapibus tortor justo, a vulputate ipsum lacinia sed. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus sit amet malesuada velit. Fusce diam neque, cursus id dui ac, blandit vehicula tortor.
Phasellus interdum ipsum eu leo condimentum, in dignissim erat tincidunt. Ut fermentum consectetur tellus, dignissim volutpat orci suscipit ac. Praesent scelerisque urna metus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis pulvinar, sem a sodales eleifend, odio elit blandit risus, a dapibus ligula orci non augue. Nullam vitae cursus tortor, eget malesuada lectus. Nulla facilisi. Cras pharetra nisi sit amet orci dignissim, a eleifend odio hendrerit.
              </p>
            </article>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="wrapperCenter">
        <div id="contentCenter">
          <section>
            <article>
              <p>
Maecenas vitae purus at orci euismod pretium. Nam gravida gravida bibendum. Donec nec dolor vel magna consequat laoreet in a urna. Phasellus cursus ultrices lorem ut sagittis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vivamus purus felis, ornare quis ante vel, commodo scelerisque tortor. Integer vel facilisis mauris.
              </p>
              <img src="images/auto1.jpg" alt="Auto 1" width="268" height="268" />
              <p>
In urna purus, fringilla a urna a, ultrices convallis orci. Duis mattis sit amet leo sed luctus. Donec nec sem non nunc mattis semper quis vitae enim. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
              </p>
            </article>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="wrapperRight">
        <div id="contentRight">
          <section>
            <article>
              <img src="images/auto2.jpg" alt="Auto 2" width="268" height="268" style="margin-top: 0" />
              <img src="images/auto3.jpg" alt="Auto 3" width="268" height="268" style="margin-top: 0" />
              <p>
Cras eu quam lobortis, sodales felis ultricies, rhoncus neque. Aenean nisi eros, blandit ac lacus sit amet, vulputate sodales mi. Nunc eget purus ultricies, aliquam quam sit amet, porttitor velit. In imperdiet justo in quam tristique, eget semper nisi pellentesque. Cras fringilla eros enim, in euismod nisl imperdiet ac.
Fusce tempor justo vitae faucibus luctus.
              </p>
            </article>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <img class="footerLogo" src="images/auto4.jpg" alt="Auto 4" width="80" height="80" />
      <p class="footerText">
Copyright &copy; Pinco Inc.
<br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
<br />Fusce ornare turpis orci, nec egestas leo feugiat ac.
<br />Morbi eget sem facilisis, laoreet erat ut, tristique odio. Proin sollicitudin quis nisi id consequat.
      </p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS File:

```
/* CSS Document */

*, body, article, secton, p { margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; }

body { background: #8B0000; /* darkred */; }

body { margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; }

div#wrapper { margin: 0 auto; width: 960px; height: 100%; background: #FFC0CB /* pink */; }

header { position: relative; background: #005b97; height: 140px; }

header div.logo { float: left; width: 360px; height: 140px; }
header div.logo img.logo { width: 360px; height: 140px;  }

header div.titolo { float: left; padding: 12px 0 0 35px; color: black; }
header div.titolo h1 { font-size: 36px; font-weight: bold; }
header div.titolo h2 { font-size: 24px; font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; color: white;}

header nav { position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0; }

header ul.menu { background: black; }
header ul.menu li { display: inline-block; padding: 3px 15px; font-weight: bold; }

div#mainContent { float: left; padding: 15px 0; height: 900px; }

#wrapperLeft { float: left; margin-left: 15px; width: 305px; }

#wrapperCenter { float: left; margin: 0 15px 0 15px; width: 290px; }

#wrapperRight { float: left; margin-right: 15px; width: 305px; }

div#contentLeft { border: 1px solid black; padding: 15px; width: 273px; height: 868px; background: #ccc; overflow: hidden; }

div#contentCenter { border: 1px solid transparent; padding: 15px; width: 258px; height: 868px; background: #E00; overflow: hidden; }

div#contentRight { border: 1px solid black; padding: 15px; width: 273px; height: 868px; background: #ccc; overflow: hidden; }

div#mainContent section { text-align: justify; }

div#mainContent img { margin: 12px 0; }

footer { clear: both; padding: 12px; background: #306; color: white; height: 80px; font-size: 12px; font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; overflow: hidden; }

footer img.footerLogo { float: right; }

a { color: white; text-decoration: none; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably caused by sub-pixel rounding.

As you zoom, your browser may calculate pixel values with fractions of pixels. As a result of rounding these values up or down, pixel-perfect layouts can break. ([Different browsers](http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/) handle this in different ways.)

I had decent luck converting your pixel values to percentage values.
Here are the values that worked for me:

```
div#contentLeft,
div#contentCenter,
div#contentRight {
     margin-left: 1.1%;
     padding: 1.56%;
     width: 28.3%;
}
```

### Edit:

Here's another method, which essentially centers the three boxes in `div#mainContent` rather than spacing them so tightly with margins. It allows them a little more room to flex when zoomed.

I removed the `margin-left` from `div#contentLeft` and added the following CSS to center the three boxes:

```
div#wrapper {
  overflow:hidden;         /* ADDED THIS TO AVOID HORIZONTAL SCROLL */
}

div#mainContent {
     position: relative;   /* ADDED THIS */
     left: 50%;            /* ADDED THIS */
     float: left;
     padding: 30px 0px;
     text-align: justify;
}

div#contentLeft {
     position: relative;   /* ADDED THIS */
     left: -50%;           /* ADDED THIS */
     background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #CCCCCC;
     border: 1px solid black;
     float: left;
     height: 900px;
     padding: 15px;
     width: 272px;
     /* margin-left:12px;     REMOVED THIS */
}

div#contentCenter {
     position: relative;   /* ADDED THIS */
     left: -50%;           /* ADDED THIS */
     background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #EE0000;
     border: 1px solid transparent;
     float: left;
     height: 900px;
     margin-left: 12px;
     padding: 15px;
     width: 272px;
}

div#contentRight {
     position: relative;   /* ADDED THIS */
     left: -50%;           /* ADDED THIS */
     background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #CCCCCC;
     border: 1px solid black;
     float: left;
     height: 900px;
     margin-left: 12px;
     padding: 15px;
     width: 272px;
}
```

The boxes remain floated on one row even when Firefox is zoomed all the way out.